# Fix "Type 'CMTime' has no member 'zero'" error in Xcode, for 16.2?

Tags: xcode, avplayer, cmtime, ios16.2

It seems that currently (14.2 (14C18)) if you use `CMTime.zero`

```
self.player?.seek(to: .zero, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

or

```
self.player?.seek(to: .zero)
```

you'll see the error

[image]

However, the project does compile and run perfectly.

For the file, I import

```
import UIKit
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
```

(And if I try removing some/all of those it makes no difference; I can't find a fix anyway.)

It seems that if you wind back to minimum deployment 16.0 (rather than current 16.2) the warnings do go away, but the behavior is a bit erratic.

Is anyone familiar with this and/or has a solution?

Comment: Weird stuff like this can usually be resolved by quitting Xcode, deleting the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder, restarting Xcode, a loading the project again.

Comment: It's a great point @HangarRash .. and indeed .. that fixes it!  I can repro the problem even after doing that, but, that seems to be the only solution.  perhaps U should put it in as an answer to help googlers...

Comment: BTW for anyone reading here, a handy way to find the derived data folder is, just tap command-comma, Locations tab, and you'll see the current location is given (tap the small circle arrow to bring it up in finder, quit xcode, then just trash the whole derived data folder).  thanks @HangarRash !!

Comment: Not advertising. Not my app. :)
I use the free DevCleaner app for convenience. It cleans up Derived Data, support files for outdated OS versions, logs, and so on, at the user's option.
https://itunes.apple.com/app/devcleaner/id1388020431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried to delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` as suggested by the comments, but they didn't work. I was able to fix it by changing the `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 5` in `Build Settings`. I was using Swift 4 previously.

[image]

My setup is Xcode 14.2, trying to build to an iPhone with iOS16.1.